# Running process in a process - no permissions

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I have one process:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = path,
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            Arguments = _uri,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "runas",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
        };
```

which is a console application which also runs a process (also console application):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi2 = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = path2,
                RedirectStandardInput = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                Arguments = _uri,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "runas",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
            };
```

I get an error

> Operation cancelled by User

when it tries to open the second console. This error vanishes when I set `UseShellExecute = false` for the second process. So I guess it is somehow a permission problem? Because running the second console for itself works.

Also the second console tries to write to a excel file which also refuses to work when run inside first console.

> "registry access is not allowed"

Comment: You are not running "a process in a process." You are starting one process from another. You use the runas verb. Is the original application running under adminsitrative rights? Is the Elevation prompt appearing properly?

Comment: Correct. Starting one process from another. The first process is started from  Debugging (Ctrl+F5) in Visual Studio (running as Administrator).

Comment: During a Debug Run VS often starts the programm under some odd temporary user. Can play havok with accessing the User folders, but also prevents damage from faulty code. And I bet it is a limited user. If a programm needs Adminsitrative rights, usually the trick is to provide a manifest that says so. I keeps sounding like a UAC/Elevetaion issue: http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/03/making-your-application-uac-aware.html

Comment: I already added a manifest with: <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: It feels like it should still ask your for elevation, but it does not. 
Try directly starting the debug compilation from teh debug folder with "Run as Admin" and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: still the same unfortunately

Comment: Do you or do you not get the Elevation Prompt? I had an issue a while back where Elevation on the whole System was not working due to faulty OS settings: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d822d603-9c4c-4358-8abb-00ee8a028e37/run-as-administrator-not-elevatingasking-for-password-properly?forum=w7itprosecurity

Comment: I do not get any prompt. Console starts but then fails to start the next one. I also have UAC disabled for the testing.

Comment: Having UAC disabeled was exactly the problem I had. Somebody was trying to be very clever, but ended up beign very dumb and forcing me to jump through hoops. try the whole programm on a fresh isntallation of Windows. Ideally just set one up in a VM (because setting them up is fast). If it works there, it is your OS Installation that is at fault. Wich happens.